# JsonGenerationException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, fasterxml

I'm trying to add an instance of this class to `neo4j spring 4.0.0.RELEASE`:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User
{
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Property
    private UUID uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID();
    @Property
    private String username;
    @Property
    private String password;

    // getters, setters, blah blah...
}
```

When I do I get this exception:

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/pegboard] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: Could not create JSON due to Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FailingSerializer.serialize(FailingSerializer.java:35) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:538) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:469) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:561) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:469) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
...more stack trace...
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The UUID property was causing this error. Because neo4j will only persist properties of primitive types + `String` this fails to be mapped without the use of a converter. To resolve create a converter:

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.AttributeConverter;

public class UUIDConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {
    @Override
    public String toGraphProperty(UUID uuid) {
        return uuid.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public UUID toEntityAttribute(String uuid) {
        return UUID.fromString(uuid);
    }
}
```

Then add a convert annotation to the UUID property in the user class:

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.Convert;

...

@Property
@Convert(UUIDConverter.class)
private UUID uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID();
```